# loop/logic issues in validating string/character data

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I need to see if the characters at the end of a string are a zip code or zip+4. If there is no zip or zip+4 at the end of this string, then this address is rejected. I don't understand why when I get to the dash character, "-", which is asci 45, my noZip becomes TRUE right here. I am returning a "Yes" from the fnIsDash function, but I leave the loop at that point.

Related to this problem -- I would like to use a regular expression to see if my string is a zip code, it would be "NNNNN-NNNN" or "NNNNN" where N is any digit. But from my research, I didn't see robust regular expression functionally in Progress. Is that true?

```
FUNCTION fnisNumeric RETURNS LOGICAL (INPUT cCharacter AS CHARACTER) FORWARD.
FUNCTION fnisDash RETURNS LOGICAL (INPUT cCharacter AS CHARACTER) FORWARD.

DEFINE VARIABLE location AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE zipPlus4Temp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE noZip AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cThisChar AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cTemp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iTemp AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

location = "124 State Road Mechanicsburg PA 17050-3156".

zipPlus4Temp = SUBSTRING (location, length(location) - 9, 10).
MESSAGE "zipPlus4Temp " + zipPlus4Temp VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
noZip = FALSE.
                                                                           
DO iTemp = 1 TO LENGTH(zipPlus4Temp):
   IF noZip EQ TRUE THEN LEAVE.
       cThisChar = SUBSTRING(zipPlus4Temp,iTemp,1).
       MESSAGE STRING(iTemp) + " this char " + cThisChar VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
       IF iTemp GE 1 AND iTemp GE 5 THEN
           IF NOT(fnIsNumeric(cThisChar)) THEN noZip = TRUE.
       //noZip becomes true here
       IF iTemp EQ 6 THEN 
           IF NOT(fnIsDash(cThisChar)) THEN noZip = TRUE.
       IF iTemp GE 7 AND iTemp GE 10 THEN 
           IF NOT(fnIsNumeric(cThisChar)) THEN noZip = TRUE. 
END.

MESSAGE SUBSTITUTE("zipPlus4Temp &1 is &2",zipPlus4Temp, noZip).

FUNCTION fnIsNumeric RETURNS LOGICAL (i_cc as CHARACTER):
    RETURN ASC(i_cc) GE 48 AND ASC(i_cc) LE 57.
END FUNCTION.

FUNCTION fnIsDash RETURNS LOGICAL (i_cc as CHARACTER):
    MESSAGE SUBSTITUTE("The character being passed is &1",i_cc) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    MESSAGE "the ascii value of the character being passed is " + STRING(ASC(i_cc)) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    RETURN ASC(i_cc) EQ 45.
END FUNCTION.
```

Comment: As a visual person I greatly dislike GT, GE, EQ, LE and LT. If you had used >, >=, =, <= and < instead, I expect you would have seen the problem with your code.

Comment: Also =,<,> etc are universally recognized. Eq etc should be thrown on the fire of historical artifacts (at least according to me)

Comment: ok, that is helpful. I'm so the habit of EQ because of the confusion with assignment "=" and equal to, but that's true, it's more readable.  Good tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your noZip variable is becoming TRUE before the dash check. You have an error in your digit 1-5 logic. The IF-THEN statement says greater than or equal to 1 and greater than or equal to 5. It should be less than or equal to 5. Change the line to this:

```
IF iTemp GE 1 AND iTemp LE 5 THEN
```

Same for the digit 7-10 check, but that isn't affecting the noZip value.

```
IF iTemp GE 7 AND iTemp LE 10 THEN
```

And no, Progress doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: oh my gosh, what a miss. Yup, better to use the operators than the letters.